# rails 3, is there a way to keep skinny controller when controller uses lots of session info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I like a nice skinny controller as much as the next guy.

But the app I'm working on talks extensively to a remote system via JSON, and the session variables are used extensively... each little interaction is a separate hit to one of dozens of controller methods, and rails' built-in session tracking keeps track of all the state.

Consequently, the controller has dozens of methods, one for each "interaction" and those methods extensively read (and sometimes write) the session.

It's my understanding that if you're accessing the session in your model methods you're doing something horribly "wrong" ... but having 100+ lines of code PER controller-method for dozens of controller methods seems "wrong" too.

Given that scenario, what IS the best tradeoff between fat controllers vs models that access the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently came across a similar problem. I was writing and application that depended heavily on a remote API that accepted/returned JSON. Subsequently, I had *very* few models in my application, and my controllers were quite lengthly.

I ended up writing a custom parser `module` in `lib/` and made calls to the Module (which handled a lot of the logic that would normally exist in the controller)

Consider the following:

```
module RemoteParser
  def get_user(user_id)
    result = ActiveSupport::JSON.parse(NetHttp.get('http://www.example.com/'))
    session[:received_user] = true
  end
end
```

Now your controllers can be skinny again:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = RemoteParser::get_user(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I'd just like to add that this is an incredibly contrived example of such uses. If you provide additional information about what your requesting, etc, I can help you further.